# scatter plot to also represent the repetition of values using color bar

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a scatter plot to also represent the number of times a specific value occurs, the data set is quiet simple and looks somewhat like this:

```
x = [555,..690,.., 300] 

Y = [3,..3.5,.., 8.6]
```

with Y having many repeated values

I used very simple code:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, s=100, c= y, cmap='PiYG', marker='o', edgecolors='black', linewidth=1, alpha=0.7)

plt.colorbar();
```

to have a output like this:

[image]

I realise with this, that I'm associating a specific colour for each value of Y, but instead I would like the colour bar to represent the number of times a certain value of Y is repeated.

Could someone please tell me how that would be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're almost there! Consider computing the desired number of occurrences with the "np.unique" function.

Edit: the initial answer assumed y elements to be integer, let me adjust it for a more general case.

Here's a small example:

```
# data
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [5.1, 5.1, 5.1, 6.2, 6.2, 7.3]

# compute the entry counts
import numpy as np
u,c = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)

# color according to the counts
color = [c[np.where(u==y[i])][0] for i in range(len(y))]

# plot the data (with the function you already used)
plt.scatter(x, y, s=100, c=color, cmap='PiYG', marker='o', edgecolors='black', linewidth=1, alpha=0.7)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: resulting image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I understand what I was missing. However, I still have a error in my output. In my case I import the data from a xls file and every time I run it I have the following error -    color = h[y]

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices.                                                                                          Could you help me here, thank you.

Comment: Hi! Please have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I was able to plot without any errors.